# iphone where are variables allocated in heap

Tags: iphone, memory-management, heap-memory

I come from a microcontroller programming world, and I am learning to program on iOS,

I have a question that is being bothering me:

- how to know the physical address of a the memory allocated to an object?

  ```
   NSString *nombre = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"nombreName"];
  ```

like the hexa address?? where to see this?

- how big is the heap? can I see the heap at the beggining and after allocating to the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gdb to inspect objects at runtime while debugging.

I've created a simple UIView object as,

```
UIView *someObject = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

and set a breakpoint on this line,

Stepping over this line so that someObject's memory is allocated, and then run `po` or print object on gdb shows the hex address of this object - `0x9304090`.

```
(gdb) po someObject
<UIView: 0x9304090; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x4b1b730>>
```

If the object's `description` method has been overridden, you may not see the hex address. For those objects, simply print the pointer

```
(gdb) p someObject
$2 = (UIView *) 0x9304090
```

or cast it to an int to see the memory location as a decimal.

```
(gdb) p (int) someObject
$3 = 154157200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use heapshots to look at status of heap and profile your application.

Example : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/3/8/using-heapshots-to-find-abandoned-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

The memory address of the object in your example would be "nombre".  You can display it like this:

```
NSLog(@"nombre address is %x", nombre);
```

As for analyzing memory heap issues, you need look no further than XCode.  Look under the run menu.  There should be an entry called "run with performance tool".  You should find everything you need there.

Comment: p.s. I don't know what to tell you about the "buttering" thing.  I think they have different web sites for that.

Comment: haha, tnx, changed now the butter!!, also what is the x?, isnt nombre a string? why x? tnx

Comment: "nombre" is definitely NOT a string!  But is does "point" at one.

Comment: With regard to butter:  I don't judge.

But the past perfect tense would be "has been bothering".  :)

Comment: If you came from the microcontroller world, then you are a long way from home!  Objective-C is weird in that is combines the low-level aspects of C (a pointer is an actual memory address) with the very high-level aspects of Smalltalk (dynamic runtime binding and using messages as function calls).